# How do I get into the center room in the Iron Keep?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In the big open area before the Smelter Demon fight there is a room in the center. You can also get there after the Smelter Demon, by climbing down the ladder. The room that spews fire out of it, especially when you open any of the doors. My curiosity has gotten the best of me, and I'm wondering if and how one would be able to turn that fire off, or at least make the room safe to go in. Is this possible, and if so is there any good loot/fun fights in there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the video, you can see how to deactivate the fire (2:20)

After you turn the hatch wheel, the fire dies down and you can enter. This is a way to circumvent the Smelter Demon boss fight.

> {brief description: at approximately the mid-point of the lowerable bridge (or to the left of the "smelter demon entrance walkway") is a walkway which leads up to a door with a circular handle. Activate the handle.}

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to check out the video when I get home from work. Also, why would you ever want to circumvent the Smelter Demon? That's one of my favorite fights to do over and over!

Comment: I will after I get a chance to watch the video, I won't be able to until tonight when I get home.